# How to split ajax result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```
$("select#product-id").change(function(){
    $("input#product-name").val("Loading...");
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/api/purchase-entry-data.php",
        data: {
            product_id : value
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            $("input#product-name").val(data);
        },
        error: function (){
            $("input#product-name").val("No Data Available");
        }
    });
});
```

I am tring to use ajax result in two places (there is two value in the ajax result 1. Product Name, 2. Product Size). 
So how to split up that that result in two different values in php.

Comment: What do you mean by 2 values in ajax result?

Comment: What does the data look like when it is returned from your AJAX?

Comment: It is something like this `var product = {desc:"Android  ", size:"5.5"}` Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends how you are returning the `data` back to ajax. There are several ways you can do this.

**Using `split`**

In your `purchase-entry-data.php` file you could return data with a separator then use `split` to get both values. Just make sure you use a separator that will not be contained in the data returned. Here I used a `pipe`

```
echo "productDesc|productSize";
```

Then in jquery you can split it up and access each element in the array

```
var result= $(data).text().split('|');
var productDesc = result[0];
var productSize = result[1];
```

**Using `JSON`**

In your php file return the data in an array and JSON

```
<?php
$arr = array('productDesc' => 'Description', 'productSize' => 'Size');
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Then in jquery access it like

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```